# How to convert datatype from nvarchar to numeric

Tags: syntax-error, sqldatatypes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP4sR.png)

I can not convert datatype from nvarchar and null to decimal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aHQp.png)
I met the error. How can I resolve it. I think I should remove null after casting the datatype. Please help me, I just a beginner to practice SQL.

Comment: Add all information as text not as image. Also add the tag for the dazabase you are using

Answer (score 1):

in SQL to convert from nvarchar to numeric you can use 2 different methods.
The first is CAST():

```
SELECT CAST('123.45' AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS ConvertedValue;
```

And the expression to use it correctly is this:
`CAST(expression AS datatype(length))`

The second is CONVERT():

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2), '123.45') AS ConvertedValue;
```

And the expression is this:
`CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)`

Comment: please help me with new question

Comment: @Vincent If my answer help you, accept it to close this thread.